# Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: No such file or directory

Tags: xamarin.android

The First Tutorial of Xamarin is not deployed . So the Emulator shows Blank Screen . Can Any one Help me . Pls find the Build Details in VS 15 .

```
1>Starting deploy AVD_GalaxyNexus_ToolsForApacheCordova ...
1>Deploying AVD_GalaxyNexus_ToolsForApacheCordova ...
1>Build started.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE;__XAMARIN_ANDROID_v1_0__;__MOBILE__;__ANDROID__;__ANDROID_1__;__ANDROID_2__;__ANDROID_3__;__ANDROID_4__;__ANDROID_5__;__ANDROID_6__;__ANDROID_7__;__ANDROID_8__;__ANDROID_9__;__ANDROID_10__;__ANDROID_11__;__ANDROID_12__;__ANDROID_13__;__ANDROID_14__;__ANDROID_15__;__ANDROID_16__;__ANDROID_17__;__ANDROID_18__;__ANDROID_19__;__ANDROID_20__;__ANDROID_21__;__ANDROID_22__;__ANDROID_23__ /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0\Mono.Android.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\Phonefirst.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /target:library /utf8output CodeFile1.cs MainActivity.cs PhonewordTranslator.cs Resources\Resource.Designer.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\Users\Pabanas\AppData\Local\Temp\MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs
1>The field 'MainActivity.count' is assigned but its value is never used
1>Phonefirst -> E:\Aims2015vesrion\Phonesoft\Phonefirst\Phonefirst\bin\Debug\Phonefirst.dll
1>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
1>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
******1>:Deployment failed
****1>Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: No such file or directory
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Util.AggregateAsyncResult.CheckError(CancellationToken token)
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbSyncClient.EndPush(IAsyncResult result)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)**********
1>Deployment failed because of an internal error: No such file or directory
1>InternalError
1>Build succeeded.
1>Deploy successfully on AVD_GalaxyNexus_ToolsForApacheCordova
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this Issue?

Comment: facing same problem

Comment: Did you solved the problem?

Comment: Also looking for this

Answer (score 0):

Try running the Android SDK, emulator, Visual studio, etc. as Administrator. This fixed the issue for me, probably it is just a workaround.